# GLib GMainContext in a thread?

Tags: c, glib

I have searched on stack overflow to find answer relevant to my problem. But i didn't find any answer.

I have a main thread (my main() function) which starts a thread. The new thread runs GMainLoop. In my main function, i keep adding sources by calling `g_io_watch` over some file descriptors. But i have getting garbage data if events are dispatched.

Below is a small part of the code that i am trying:

```
GMainLoop *loop;

gpointer event_loop_thread(gpointer arg)
{   
    g_main_loop_run(loop);
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);
    return NULL;
}

int init()
{
    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    g_thread_new(NULL, event_loop_thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}

gboolean __hci_service(GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data)
{
    // Doing something
    return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
    init();
    int _adapter_id = hci_devid("hci0");
    int hci_dev = hci_open_dev(_adapter_id);
    GIOChannel *p_hci_io = g_io_channel_unix_new(dev_id);

    GIOCondition cond = (GIOCondition)(G_IO_IN);
    g_io_add_watch(p_hci_io, cond, __hci_service, NULL);

    while (true);
    // I will close file descriptor
    return 0;

}
```

However, if i try this code, then everything works as expected:

```
GMainLoop *loop;

gpointer event_loop_thread(gpointer arg)
{   
    g_main_loop_run(loop);
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);
    return NULL;
}

int init()
{
    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    g_thread_new(NULL, event_loop_thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}

gboolean __hci_service(GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data)
{
    // Doing something
    return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
    // init();
    int _adapter_id = hci_devid("hci0");
    int hci_dev = hci_open_dev(_adapter_id);
    GIOChannel *p_hci_io = g_io_channel_unix_new(dev_id);

    GIOCondition cond = (GIOCondition)(G_IO_IN);
    g_io_add_watch(p_hci_io, cond, __hci_service, NULL);

    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    g_main_loop_run(loop);
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);

    while (true);
    // I will close file descriptor
    return 0;

}
```

---

Edit:

I have tried passing the default GMainContext of the main thread to the newly created thread. Have a look. Tell me if my approach is correct.

```
GMainLoop *loop;

gpointer event_loop_thread(gpointer arg)
{   
    GMainContext *context = (GMainContext *)arg;
    loop = g_main_loop_new(context, FALSE);
    g_main_context_push_thread_default(context);
    g_main_loop_run(loop);
    g_main_loop_unref(loop);
    return NULL;
}

int init()
{

    g_thread_new(NULL, event_loop_thread, (gpointer)g_main_context_default());
    return 0;
}

gboolean __hci_service(GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data)
{
    // Doing something
    return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
    init();
    int _adapter_id = hci_devid("hci0");
    int hci_dev = hci_open_dev(_adapter_id);
    GIOChannel *p_hci_io = g_io_channel_unix_new(dev_id);

    GIOCondition cond = (GIOCondition)(G_IO_IN);
    g_io_add_watch(p_hci_io, cond, __hci_service, NULL);

    //loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    //g_main_loop_run(loop);
    //g_main_loop_unref(loop);

    while (true);
    // I will close file descriptor
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `GMainContext` if you want to run a main loop from a thread.  From the Glib's [main loop documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.description):

> To allow multiple independent sets of sources to be handled in
>   different threads, each source is associated with a GMainContext. A
>   GMainContext can only be running in a single thread, but sources can
>   be added to it and removed from it from other threads.

When you create a main loop with `g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);`, while it's  handy to *not* specify any GMainContext, you need to pass a GMainContext from which you want your loop if you want to run the loop in a different thread.  You can create a `GMainContext` with `g_main_context_new()` and pass it to `g_main_loop_new()`, or use `g_main_context_get_thread_default()` to get the default main context for the running thread.

[`g_io_add_watch()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-add-watch) is yet another handy version of the function, which

> Adds the GIOChannel into the default main loop context with the
>   default priority.

Unfortunately, there is no `g_io_add_watch()` variant function to specify a main context, you have to manually create a `GSource` from your `GIOChannel`, `p_hci_io`, and attach to your context via [`g_source_attach()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-attach).  Note that [`g_io_add_watch_full()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-add-watch-full) also works with the default main context.

The reason your second code works is that you created your main loop in the main thread which has your source attached.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please have a look at the edited section

Comment: "The reason your second code works is that you overwritten the global variable loop with the loop from the default main context, which has your source attached." - My second version don't overwrite the global loop variable. I have commented out init() function call in my main() function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already passing GMainContext of the main thread to newly created thread. In the newly created thread, i am creating the main loop using GMainContext of the main thread. I am adding sources to the global GMainContext so that newly thread will dispatch them in case of events. Am i missing something? Can you include any code with your answer?

Comment: Did it work? I'd call `g_main_context_default()` in `event_loop_thread()` but ...

Comment: Yes it is working. But if i try to add a source via g_io_add_watch() second time, then it's callback is not being called.
Can you explain it?